# Can't import { next } from 'express' in Typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I have this line of code:

`import {response, request, next} from 'express'`

However, i get this error from the typescript compiler, in vscode:

`Module '"express"' has no exported member 'next'.`

EDIT: I'm importing these types in a file different from my "server.ts", therefore I would like (if possible, of course) a solution that would keep my code lean, and import just what is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's feedback.

I installed express with an "npm i express" and the version that came with it was: `version 4.18.1`. For this version, I solved the problem by using `npm i @types/express`, and, then, using "NextFunction" as the type (e.g.: `import {Response, Request, NextFunction} from 'express'`  and then `const auth = async (req : Request,res : Response , next: NextFunction)`)

Answer (score 0):

Try importin the express like this:

```
import express from 'express';
```

After you created the expressApp, you can use it like this with your endpoint:

```
this.expressApp.post('endpointName', async (req, res, next) => { })
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However, I need to use 'next' in a file different from where I use the instance of the express app. I would like not to import the whole 'express', since i'm using only the types "request,response,next" in this particular file

Answer (score 0):

The correct type for the `next` callback argument is `NextFunction`:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

export default function (req : Request , res : Response, next : NextFunction ) {
  …
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I still have this error: " Module '"express"' has no exported member 'NextFunction'. " . Note that I have express in my npm file's dependencies, and other express types (request and response) are being imported successfully. Also, if I sue capital letter (eg. Request, Response), I will have the error "Module '"express"' has no exported member 'Request' ". the same for capitalized Response.

Comment: @VitorHugo sounds like you're using outdated type declarations for Express, [the current ones](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts) don't export `request/response` (lower case) as types, and [exports the `NextFunction`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L111) interface that I'm using.

Comment: once again, thanks for your help. I'm using express version "express": "^4.18.1" (taken from the package.json "dependendies"). I solved it by using the command 'npm i @types/express'